# How to set a cookie per user in php?

Tags: php, html, cookies, session-cookies, session-state

I'm using cookies on a php page I've developed as follows:

```
setcookie("ThisCookie[to]", $toValue, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), "/");
```

If I detect the cookie is set, I retrieve the values:

```
       foreach ($_COOKIE["ThisCookie"] as $name => $value) {
        if ($name == "to")
        {
            $cookie_to = $value;


        }
```

This works just fine at first glance, however no matter what machine I visit the page from, I get the SAME values returned from the cookie. So for example, on my desktop computer I enter a value of "ABC" and that gets stored for this cookie. I see "ABC" returned if I visit the site from a different computer, or even my phone.

Am I severely misunderstanding how cookies work? I thought they were stored on the local machine per user and not common to all users. Why is the same value being returned from the cookie no matter which machine I visit the page from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it all wrong fellow...

Cookies are user's and are stored on the user's machine.

When you process the `$_COOKIE` variable in php, you process a specific user's cookie (the one that made the request) that was passed in the header.

For the server read about `$_SESSION` http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: So you're saying I shouldn't be seeing the behavior I'm seeing and each machine should be able to have it's own value for the cookie?

Comment: It does... the key is `ThisCookie` and the value is what you set ... so each machine will return what you set on it.